# PostgreSQL get column with date + interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have table with a two columns:

- date (timestamp)
- milliseconds (int)

How could I write a query that would return the two columns and a third column that represents a sum of the first two as a timestamp.

Like this:

```
            date            | milliseconds  |              sum          
----------------------------+---------------+----------------------------
 2014-12-10 17:43:47.554989 |         11882 | 2014-12-10 17:43:59.436989
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you answer is as follows:

```
# select date, milliseconds, date+milliseconds*interval '1 milliseconds' as sum from temp;

             date            | milliseconds |            sum
 ----------------------------+--------------+----------------------------
  2014-12-10 17:43:47.554989 |        11882 | 2014-12-10 17:43:59.436989
 (1 row)
```

I created a temp table with your timestamp field called date, and your int field called milliseconds.  Then ran the above select off the table with your values in it.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add it as an interval:

```
select stamp + (ms / 1000) * '1 second'::interval
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you are looking for is

```
 date + milliseconds * INTERVAL '1 MILLISECOND';
```